# Language switcher, consulting browser's localStorage

Tags: typescript, i18n, angular-2+, browser-storage

I'm using angular 6 and ngx-translate. This is my switch language function

```
  switchLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    if (language !== 'ar' && document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].hasAttribute('dir')) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].removeAttribute('dir');
    } else if (language === 'ar' && !document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].hasAttribute('dir')) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
    }
    // if this line worth it?
    if (language !== JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lang'))) {
    localStorage.setItem('lang', JSON.stringify(language));
    }
  }
```

I'm asking about this line in particular

```
if (language !== JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lang')))
```

If I don't use it, it means that if the language is english and you switch it to english, the localStorage is going to be updated. If I use it however, it means that, every time you switch a language, it's going to read  localstorage to check its value before updating.

Is the cost of just setting the language better than the cost of checking it first?

This method is getting called whenever you switch the language and in `app.ts` constructor, so basically on every page load. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Lack of context: Please update your question with the HTML being used.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix what html? I don't use html, this all i have, I don't understand your question. What would html have to do with localstorage? Maybe I misunderstood your question

Comment: `document.getElementById` tends to imply that HTML is being used.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix for that please read my question and scroll down to see my own answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154725/how-to-switch-to-html-rtl-from-a-component

Comment: All code should be inline and in the question. Reviewers should not have to profile hop to find your code.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix you're absolutely correct but it's not needed, you asked about something that is not relevant to that question, all it's doing is changing `dir="ltr"` whenever someone switches to arabic. The whole question is about whether or not to check the default language with localstorage whenever the language is switched; and if there's a better way to do it my friend. Anyhow, I guess it's solved. I wanted to know the write time

Comment: I see your point, but at the minimum you should explain the structure of the HTML in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite of LocalStorage is normal practice because of a rewrite time ~equal check time.

You can change the code.

```
localStorage.setItem('lang', language);
```

By the way `JSON.parse` and  `JSON.stringify` is unnecessary actions in your code because `language` is already `string`.

---

*I only considered the code associated with your the question.*